# Understanding low level file routines

Tags: c, file, operating-system, gnu

I am going through Mark Burgess's "The GNU C Programming Tutorial". I have come across the following information:

> Even though low-level fle routines do not use buﬀering, and once you call write, your data can be read from the file immediately, it may take up to a minute before your data is physically written to disk. (Page:142)

Firstly, is "it may take up to a minute(some time) before your data is written to disk" true?

Secondly, when low level file routines are not using buffering why will the delay take place?

Comment: The book is wrong. There is no specific time when the data is actually on disc. But that is true for all normal file-IO. You might want to read about OS. Does the book say there is no buffering **at all** or just by the file-functions?

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, the book says there is no concept of buffering in case of low level file routines.

Comment: _Sigh_ Read my comment **carefully** again! Then think about it! Then google (or whatever you use to lookup "linux file buffering")!

Answer (score 1):

There are two places where I/O buffering can occur (at least — it could be more than just two).

One is in the application; the standard I/O functions using `FILE *` use buffered I/O unless you use `setvbuf()` to prevent it.

The other is in the kernel.  Disk I/O normally goes into the kernel buffer pool, and eventually gets written by the kernel to disk.  There are ways around that (`O_DIRECT` on Linux; raw devices on classic Unix; etc).  The key point is that the `write()` system call normally writes to he kernel buffer pool.  The kernel takes responsibility for ensuring that the data is written to disk safely and correctly (journalling, …).

The kernel doesn't write everything to disk immediately because (a) you may add more changes to the data, (b) other people may need to read or write the data, (c) the disk drive may be busy writing something else at the other end of its 1 TiB of storage and it will take time to get the write head in position to take your data, and it would be better for the overall performance of the system if it scheduled other work before writing your changed buffer to disk.  It will get written to disk.  It is just not defined when, and it could be fractions of a second or multiple seconds or longer, though most often it will not take minutes for the data to be written to disk.

These days, there could also be buffering in the RAID controllers, and maybe in the individual disks inside the RAID setup, and maybe there's network buffering too if it is a remotely-mounted file system.  Those add extra levels of buffering.

The `read()` and `write()` and related low-level I/O functions do not have any client-side (application) buffering — unlike the standard C I/O functions.

Answer (score 0):

A file is said to be *buffered*, when its contents are not outputted or inputted directly. Instead, the file's bytes are written to a temporary buffer in memory.

For example, if you are reading from a file, you are reading from the buffer. Once you have read all the characters in the buffer, it is replenished with new bytes from the file. The reason for this indirectness, is that a memory read is much faster than a hard disk read.

The calls `read` and `write` are low-level, and do not perform buffering. The `stdio.h` calls like `getc` and `putc`, do use buffering. These higher-level APIs only call the low level ones, when the buffer must be replenished.

Comment: I understand what you have said, but my question is why will the delay take place?

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the hard drive is much slower than writing to RAM. When you write to a drive it writes to memory, but doesn't always write to the disk immediately. The data might not be written to disk until that part of memory needs to be overwritten to make room for something else. This is called a Write-Back cache.